# How to manage queue through RabbitMQ and spin more workers depending on queue size

Tags: memory-management, queue, rabbitmq, worker

I am trying to see if I can make my rabbitmq spin up another worker if the messages in the queue reach the size of the queue or certain limit that i would specify in rabbitmq, instead of me monitoring the queue and starting another instance of worker manually.Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that one solution could be that you have a "Queue" worker that manages a pool of "Consumers" workers. The "Queue" worker polls continuously the queue asking the count of queue messages. When the messages count reach some threshold (going up or down), the "Queue" worker starts a consumer taking it from the pool or stops a running consumer.

The "Queue" worker has to maintain the state of the number of active consumers in order to understand if it has to start a new "Consumer" worker.

A raw example or the formula to use to calculate if it is necessary to start/stop a new consumer could be:

START integer_part(number_of_messages_in_queue / threshold) > active_cosumers_workers_count

STOP integer_part(number_of_messages_in_queue / threshold) < active_cosumers_workers_count

Example:

- threshold = 10
- number of messages in queue = 49
- active consumers workers count = 4

integer_part(49 / 10) > 4 --> 4 > 4 --> false (do nothing)

integer_part(49 / 10) > 4 --> 4 < 4 --> false (do nothing)

- threshold = 10
- number of messages in queue = 50
- active consumers workers count = 4

integer_part(50 / 10) > 4
 --> 5 > 4 = true (spin new "Worker" consumer)

- threshold = 10
- number of messages in queue = 39
- active consumers workers count = 4

integer_part(39 / 10) < 4
 --> 3 < 4 = true (stop a "Worker" consumer)

Answer (score 0):

The rabbitmq-management plugin provides an HTTP-based API for management and monitoring of your RabbitMQ server. An idea is to poll the HTTP API queue length and spin up or take down workers depending on the length.